# XCode 4 gSOAP Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webservice-client, gsoap

I am writing a client for SOAP based web service.
I am using gSOAP and it works fine in <strike>release</strike> and debug builds but cannot do a profiling with instruments.

These error pops out:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_soap_set_recv_logfile", referenced from:
      _main2 in gSOAPService.o
  "_soap_set_test_logfile", referenced from:
      _main2 in gSOAPService.o
  "_soap_set_sent_logfile", referenced from:
      _main2 in gSOAPService.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Functions referenced here are used to suppress gSOAP logging which drastically slows down application execution time regarding request/response sequence.

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

It may help you . Go to **Build settings** in the **Targets** . There you can find the **valid architecture** row. (Remove the armv7s only use the armv7) .

Comment: Thank you for answering. That's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

These functions are only present if `SOAP_DEBUG` is defined. When running Release or Profile this directive was turned off.

Solved it by putting `#ifdef SOAP_DEBUG` before calling those functions.

```
#ifdef SOAP_DEBUG
    soap_set_sent_logfile(soap, NULL);
    soap_set_recv_logfile(soap, NULL);
    soap_set_test_logfile(soap, NULL);
#endif
```